# What kind of creatures are subject to Phantom Rogue's Tokens of the Departed?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue

This might get a little fiddly, but I was curious how people would rule on this aspect of Phantom Rogue's level 13 feature, "Tokens of the Departed"

> When a life ends in your presence, you’re able to snatch a token from
> the departing soul, a sliver of its life essence that takes physical
> form: as a reaction when a creature you can see dies within 30 feet of
> you, you can open your free hand and cause a Tiny trinket to appear
> there, a soul trinket. The DM determines the trinket’s form or has you
> roll on the Trinkets table in the Player’s Handbook to generate it.

Do you think that the creature necessarily needs a soul to be able to use this feature? IE, would this work on undead or constructs? Flavor text uses "soul" but RAW mechanic just says "when a creature dies" and "has soul", and "does not have soul" aren't properties of a stat-block.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The ability works on any Creature.

Though the trinket is called a soul trinket, nowhere in the rules does it specify what types of creatures can be claimed for this ability.  Various other abilities in the books do clarify that they do not work on Constructs or Undead, such as the spell [*Blight*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Blight#content):

> ...This spell has no Effect on Undead or Constructs.

Or the Paladin's ability [*Lay on Hands*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Paladin#toc_5):

> ...This feature has no Effect on Undead and Constructs.

As the Phantom's ability has no such stipulation, it can be assumed to work on all creatures.